# Max Flow Given Constraints on Edges

Tags: graph, max-flow, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Hey so I have a graph such as where 3 edges go into a node, and 3 edges come out, however I only need the outgoing edge to activate if a particular in-going edge had capacity. For instance if we have:

A -> N

B -> N

C -> N

N -> N'

N' -> A'

N' -> B'

N' -> C'

I only want flow through A' if A had flow, and flow through B' if B had flow etc etc.

Basically its a capacity limiter on on the edges A, B, C and I could not limit their capacity initially.

How can I add this constraint to max flow and solve the max flow graph problem for the given graph supposing this scenario occurs multiple times?

Edit: I cannot also limit their capacity finally because A', B', and C' are used later on in the graph so I cannot move N and N' to the end and force the combined capacity to be less later on.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to limit the combined flow leaving a, b and c to the capacity of n->n', then simply move your n nodes to the other side of your graph.  In other words, you can model your problem simply by taking the flow from a, b and c and directing it directly (or through their prime pairs) to n, then from n directly (or again through n') to your sink.

Edit: you can also put the n before a/b/c for the same effect.

Edit 2: If you're talking about an implementation of ford fulkerson, you could theoretically filter out paths you don't want in listing augmenting paths.  For example, when your program identifies a possible augmenting path, don't augment along it if it leaves flow a->n not equal to n'->a' etc.

Comment: See the thing is I can't because I need to use a, b, c later on again. Basically I can modify the n->n' part but other than that I can't really change much of the graph.

Comment: @user3892614 if my edit doesn't help with this you're going to need to give more info in your question b/c this is starting to feel like an XY problem

Comment: I already stated in my question I cannot put the limiter initially...

"Basically its a capacity limiter on on the edges A, B, C and I could not limit their capacity initially."

Comment: Then your problem makes no sense.. If you can't change anything in your graph how are you going to change it?

Comment: I was asking how can I compute the max flow given that constraint. Like one way was to use conditionals when doing the augmenting paths algorithm, but that got an exponential running time. I can change what happens between A, B, C and A', B', and C'.